# Call to non-static member function without an object argument compiler error

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I am working on a project for my intro to c++ class which is to build a program to calculate various statistics. I have the calculations down, but our professor wants us to use `std::istream` to collect the input from a file. The program will keep collecting information from the file until it reaches an End of File marker. I am very unfamiliar with the way `std::istream` works and I keep encountering this error when I try to compile.

> main.cpp:5:10: error: call to non-static member function without an
>   object argument   stats::getInput(std::cin);

Here is my stats.cpp file:

```
#include "stats.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

stats::stats(){
}

std::vector <double> stats::getInput(std::istream& input_stream){

  std::vector <double> stream;
  double x;

  while(input_stream){

    input_stream >> x;
    // std::cout << "your list of numbers is: " << x << std::endl;

    if(input_stream){
      stream.push_back(x);
    }

  }

  return stream;
}
```

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef _STATS_
#define _STATS_
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

class stats{

 public:
  stats();
  std::vector <double> getInput(std::istream& input_stream);

 private:



};

#endif
```

and here is my main.cpp file:

```
#include "stats.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  stats::getInput(std::cin);
}
```

Like I said, I am a beginner in c++ so the answer is probably fairly simple, but c++ is vastly different than Python. I have seen similar questions, but none of them have helped me figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_STATS_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message from the compiler is very clear.

`getInput` is a non-`static` member function of the class.

You need an object of the class to be able to use that member function.

Instead of

```
stats::getInput(std::cin);
```

use

```
stats obj;
obj.getInput(std::cin);
```

---

Another solution.

Since the class does not have any member variables, you may change `getInput` to a `static` member functions.

```
class stats {

   public:
      stats();
      static std::vector <double> getInput(std::istream& input_stream);

   private:
};
```

If you do that, you may use:

```
stats::getInput(std::cin);
```

---

Also, your loop to read the data can be simplified to:

```
while (input_stream >> x){
  stream.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: The function does not use any class members , so making it `static` might be a better solution