# Error while compiling LLVM code: "call to non-static member function without an object argument"

Tags: clang, llvm

I am working on an LLVM task where I need to create a custom LLVM attribute, named IsFragile. The task involves iterating over each control flow graph in the program and comparing basic block source locations against a given input. If any basic block's location overlaps with the provided source ranges, I need to mark the associated function (function containing the basic block) with the custom attribute IsFragile. Additionally, I have to display the functions marked as IsFragile, including their full signature (parameter names, types, and return type), the size of the function in terms of lines of code, and the name of the source file containing the function definition.

I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/CFG.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DebugInfoMetadata.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Attributes.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"
#include "llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h"
#include <memory>
#include "llvm/IR/DebugLoc.h"

struct FragileCluster {
    llvm::DebugLoc start;
    llvm::DebugLoc end;
};

struct FragileCluster cluster;

#define LLVM_CUSTOM_ATTR_IsFragile "is_fragile"

FragileCluster clusters[] = {
      {llvm::DebugLoc::get(1, 0, nullptr), llvm::DebugLoc::get(5, 0, nullptr)},
      {llvm::DebugLoc::get(10, 0, nullptr), llvm::DebugLoc::get(15, 0, nullptr)}
}; 

static llvm::Attribute getFragileAttr(llvm::LLVMContext &Ctx) {
    return llvm::Attribute::get(Ctx, LLVM_CUSTOM_ATTR_IsFragile, "true");
}

void markFragileFunctions(llvm::Module &M, llvm::DebugLoc start, llvm::DebugLoc end) {
    for (llvm::Function &F : M) {
        if (F.isDeclaration())
            continue;

        for (llvm::BasicBlock &BB : F) {
            llvm::DebugLoc BBStart = BB.getTerminator()->getDebugLoc();
            if (BBStart && BBStart->getLine() >= start->getLine() && BBStart->getLine() <= end->getLine()) {
                F.addFnAttr(getFragileAttr(F.getContext()));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void collectAndDisplayFragileFunctions(llvm::Module &M) {
    llvm::outs() << "Fragile Functions:\n";
    llvm::outs() << "--------------------------------------------------\n";

    for (llvm::Function &F : M) {
        if (F.hasFnAttribute(LLVM_CUSTOM_ATTR_IsFragile)) {
            llvm::outs() << "Function: " << F.getName() << "\n";
            llvm::outs() << "Signature: " << *F.getReturnType() << " " << F.getName() << "(";
            bool isFirstParam = true;
            for (llvm::Argument &Arg : F.args()) {
                if (!isFirstParam)
                    llvm::outs() << ", ";
                isFirstParam = false;
                llvm::outs() << *Arg.getType() << " " << Arg.getName();
            }
            llvm::outs() << ")\n";

            unsigned functionSize = 0;
            for (llvm::BasicBlock &BB : F)
                functionSize++;

            llvm::outs() << "Function Size: " << functionSize << " lines of code\n";

            if (llvm::DISubprogram *SP = F.getSubprogram()) {
                llvm::outs() << "Source File: " << SP->getFilename() << "\n";
            }

            llvm::outs() << "--------------------------------------------------\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    llvm::LLVMContext context;
    std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module> M = std::make_unique<llvm::Module>("MyModule", context);

    llvm::SMDiagnostic Err;
    M = llvm::parseIRFile("example.bc", Err, context);

    if (!M) {
        Err.print("MyLLVMPass", llvm::errs());
        return 1;
    }

    llvm::DebugLoc start;
    llvm::DebugLoc end;

    markFragileFunctions(*M, start, end);
    collectAndDisplayFragileFunctions(*M);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile the code with the following command:

```
clang++ -g -O3 -std=c++11 `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs` MyLLVMPass.cpp -o MyLLVMPass
```

I get the following error:

```
MyLLVMPass.cpp:30:22: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    {llvm::DebugLoc::get(1, 0, nullptr), llvm::DebugLoc::get(5, 0, nullptr)},
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
MyLLVMPass.cpp:30:58: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    {llvm::DebugLoc::get(1, 0, nullptr), llvm::DebugLoc::get(5, 0, nullptr)},
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
MyLLVMPass.cpp:32:22: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    {llvm::DebugLoc::get(10, 0, nullptr), llvm::DebugLoc::get(15, 0, nullptr)}
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
MyLLVMPass.cpp:32:59: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    {llvm::DebugLoc::get(10, 0, nullptr), llvm::DebugLoc::get(15, 0, nullptr)}
```

I'm not sure what is causing these errors. Can anyone please help me resolve them?

Comment: You are calling `static` function `get` from `llvm::DebugLoc` but `llvm::DebugLoc`  doesn't have that `static` function. It has `member` function `get`. That is why you see this error: `call to non-static member function without an object argument`, because you need object to invoke member function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to non-static member function without an object argument compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145590/call-to-non-static-member-function-without-an-object-argument-compiler-error)